# Enviar ruta completa no fake de archivos desde js a python

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7

hola tengo un problema ya que en mi interfaz hecha con js html gracias a EEL tengo un input file el cual me permite subir archivos; no necesito enviar el archivo ya q eso lo hare desde el servidor con python pero si necesito recuperar la ruta completa del archivo y enviarla a python para que este procese el archivo. el problema es que por seguridad desde js solo se envia una ruta fake y no la ruta real del archivo y ps al llegar esa rut python no encuentra el archivo. ¿ saben como puedo solucionar esto ya q si o si la ruta se debe enviar desde la interfaz? agradezco a quienes me puedan ayudar con esto.

Comment: Si bueno, como viste, no podes, porque si es mandar un archivo, que importa la ruta de donde salio??? aca el problema obviamente es otro... porque si queres una ruta, tenes que describir una ruta, lo cual hace que sea ilogico, porque entonces porque tenes una pagina web con un python atras para obtener una ruta del lugar donde estas????